# Zebra-effect table affects array environments

Tags: tables, color, rowcolor

The left delimiter of matrix environment is missing when I apply the zebra-effect using `\rowcolors{1}{cyan!20}{yellow!20}`. How can we prevent the zebra-effect from those environments?

[image: Missing Left Delimiter]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\rowcolors{1}{cyan!20}{yellow!20}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \caption{Matrice}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}
            \hline
            Environment & Example & Result\\
            \hline
            \texttt{matrix}&\lstinline|\begin{matrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{matrix}|&$ \begin{matrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{matrix} $\\
            \hline
            \texttt{bmatrix}&\lstinline|\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}|&$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix} $\\
            \hline
            \texttt{Bmatrix}&\lstinline|\begin{Bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{Bmatrix}|&$ \begin{Bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{Bmatrix} $\\
            \hline
            \texttt{pmatrix}&\lstinline|\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}|&$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} $\\
            \hline
            \texttt{vmatrix}&\lstinline|\begin{vmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{vmatrix}|&$ \begin{vmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{vmatrix} $\\
            \hline
            \texttt{Vmatrix}&\lstinline|\begin{Vmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{Vmatrix}|&$ \begin{Vmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{Vmatrix} $\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```